# Find maximum value from 2 dimensional array & addition of all the values before the maximum value & multiply the all values after the maximum value

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
  int a[4][4] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 15, 6, 5 },
      { 4, 3, 2, 1 } };

  int max = a[0][0];
  int mIndexF, mIndexE, addition = 0, multiplication = 1, i, j, status = 0, k,
      l;

  // this is for find out maximum value
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      if (max < a[i][j]) {
        max = a[i][j];
        mIndexF = i;
        mIndexE = j;
      }
    }
  }

  for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
      if ((a[k][l] < max) && (status == 0)) {
        addition += a[k][l];
      } else {
        status++;
        if (a[k][l] != max) {
          multiplication *= a[k][l];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  printf("Addition is %d\n", addition);
  printf("Multiplication is %d", multiplication);
  return 0;
}
```

I want to find the maximum value. Also want to print addition of the values which are in before of the maximum value and want to print multiply value of the values which are in after the maximum value.

Comment: You stated what you want. What is your question?

Comment: If i write code to find the maximum value from it i will get 17. In the before of 17 I putted 10, 11 in the array as integer value. I want to print the addition value of 10 and 11.

Also i have putted 3, 4, 5, 6, 2 after the maximum value and want to print the multiply value of 3, 4, 5, 6, 2. @das-g

Comment: Can you show us any effort you put into it? Anything specific you're struggling with? This still looks like no question to me.

Comment: I have no problem understanding your statements, @sohag513. But you haven't asked any question about them. What would you like to know?

Comment: i'm newbie in c. I can only find the maximum value from multi dimensional array. But I want to know what will be the code? @das-g

Comment: The purpose of this site is to help you with a specific problem, if you show that you've tried to solved it yourself first (provide some code/research). We won't write the code for you.

Comment: @sohag513 add it to your answer with proper formatting + some explanation/questions about why doesn't it do what you expect and what it does instead... and I'd advise you to read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See my question. I've updated it.. @Tlacenka

Comment: If `a[0][0]` is the max, `int mIndexF, mIndexE` are left uninitialized.

Comment: `} else {` needs work.  Should be _something_ to know we are _after_ the max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
#define MAX_INT (((unsigned int)(-1))>>1)
#define MIN_INT (~(MAX_INT))

void minmax(int a[4][4])
{
    int i, j, maxi=0, maxj=0, max=MIN_INT, sum=0, mul=1;
    // this is for find out maximum value
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (max < a[i][j]) {
                max = a[i][j];
                maxi = i;
                maxj = j;
            }
        }
    }
    // this is to add and multiply
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (i< maxi || (i==maxi && j<maxj)) // this is "before" 
                 sum += a[i][j];
            else if (i==maxi && j==maxj)        // this is "same" 
                 ;                              //..nothing to do
            else mul *= a[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("i,j=%d,%d; sum= %d, mul= %d\n", maxi, maxj, sum, mul);
}
```

EDIT: Added definitions of MAX_INT and MIN_INT

Comment: @chux, `maxi` is only the index of the array where the last maximum was found. It is needed in the second loop to know when to stop adding and start multiplying.

Comment: On 2nd thought - if all numbers were negative.  `maxi = maxj = 0`, even if `a[0][0]` was not the maximum.  Otherwise- this code has the right approach.

Comment: with this arrayint a[4][4]={{7, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 5, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 20, 6}, {1, 2, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9}}; what should be the output

my out put is i,j=2,2; sum= 54, mul= 240 I think it's not the correct output @PaulOgilvie

Comment: @sohag513, 1) "you think" is not very deterministic. 2) show me where the algoritm is wrong or 3) show me motivated what the answer should be. Besides, you provide too may initializers (so you couldn't have got an answer).

Comment: @chux, you removed (or edited) your original comment; now I'am left with a dangling reply, (and yes, `max` should be initialized to `MIN_INT` or so - fixed that; thx).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct: just initialize

```
max=INT_MIN using include<limits.h>
```

Your second loops seems to slight inappropriate you could use:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    if(status==0)
        add+=disp[i][j];
    else if(status==1)
        mul*=disp[i][j];
    if(i==loc_i && j==loc_j)
        status=1;

}
```

Afterwards just subtract

```
add-=disp[mIndexF][mIndexE];
```

Comment: `if(i==loc_i && j==loc_j) status=1;` needs to be in the middle. E.g. `if(status) mul*=disp[i][j]; else if (i==loc_i && j==loc_j) status=1; else add+=disp[i][j];`  (cancel all this, I now see `add-=disp[mIndexF][mIndexE];`

Comment: Its actually taking product correctly just adding maxx to the sum that i have figured out from the statement add - =disp[mIndexF][mIndexE];

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main(){

    int a[4][4]={
    {10,11,12,13},
    {14,15,16,17},
    {18,19,20,21},
    {22,2,3,3}
    };

    int max = a[0][0],mIndexF,mIndexE,addition = 0,multiplication =    1,i,j,status=0,k,l;

    // this is for find out maximum value
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
    if(max<a[i][j]){
    max = a[i][j];
    mIndexF=i;
    mIndexE=j;
    }
    }
    }

    printf("The maximum value is %d\n", max);

    for(k=0;k<4;k++){
    for(l=0;l<4;l++){
    if((a[k][l]<max) &&(status==0)){
    addition+=a[k][l];
    }else{
    status++;
    if(a[k][l]!=max){
    multiplication*=a[k][l];
    }
    }
    }
    }

    printf("Addition is %d\n",addition);
    printf("Multiplication is %d",multiplication);
    return 0;
    }
```